# Having some problem on using map() method on my react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app i have an initial state in a component App.js it's an array of objects

Here is App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

// Import Used Components
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import Playlist from '../PlayList/PlayList';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name: 'name1',artist: 'artist1',album: 'album1',id: 1},
      {name: 'name2',artist: 'artist2',album: 'album2',id: 2}]
    };
  }

  // Adding JSX to App Component
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I passed this initial state as a prop called searchResults to another component named .

Here is searchResults.js code :

```
import './SearchResults.css';

import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

then I used passed this prop to another component called TrackList

here is TrackList.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';

import Track from '../Track/Track';


class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />;
                    } )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

In Track.js I want to map through this initial state array to render a component called Track

here is the Track.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';

class Track extends React.Component {


    renderAction() {
        if (this.props.isRemoval){
            return <botton className='Track-action'>-</botton>;
        } else {
            return <botton className='Track-action'>+</botton>;
        }
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Track">
                <div className="Track-information">
                    <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
                    <p>{this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
                </div>
                <button className="Track-action">{this.renderAction}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Track;
```

But something is wrong !! I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

---

Here is searchBar.js component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchBar">
                <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" />
                <button className="SearchButton">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**HERE LINK TO THE PROJECT WITH THE SAME ERROR ON SANDBOX**
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-dawn-lwbxb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: What component is the error occurring in?

Comment: TrackList component , the one that has the map method

Comment: Does your ```searchResults``` state always contain the same result or is it dynamic.  If so, please show this in your App component.

Comment: If you can create an app on something like codesandbox, it would be better

Comment: @Michael for now it will always contain the same results

Comment: Is `this.state = {
      searchResults: [...]
    };` the actual code you are testing with?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I added the searchBar component in the question!!

Comment: @epascarello yes I'm trying to map through this.state.searchResults

Comment: check out [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-waterfall-8g2mw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @moufed can u till me where is the error in my code ??

Comment: inside ```Track.js ```  i removed ```this.renderAction``` and it's done

Comment: @AhmedEldawody You need to create a reproducible example in order for us to help you. @moufed fixed an error for you in his sandbox, but the `map` error  is not reproducible. Can you also share your Playlist component?

Comment: @prabhu [Here is the project on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-dawn-lwbxb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I add a sandbox link in the Question , Hope any one could help.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `TrackList` component to this:

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks && this.props.tracks.map(track => {
          return <Track key={track.id} track={track}/>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can't map through `this.props.tracks` if it is `undefined`.

The `&&` (AND operator) is a concise way to conditionally render in React. You can think of it like a simple if statement: If the expression on the left is true, then do x.

---

I'll also expand on why the `this.props.tracks` was undefined in a certain instance in your case.

The reason that this problem is happening is your `Playlist` component. If you uncomment this component from your `App` you will notice your original code will work.

This is because your `PlayList` component, like your `SearchResults` component, also renders your `TrackList` component. The problem is you haven't passed your state and props down to `TrackList` like you did with your `SearchResults` component.

So an alternative solution would be to pass your state and props down from `PlayList` to `TrackList`:

App.js

```
// ...
<SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
<Playlist searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
// ...
```

PlayList.js

```
// ...
<TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
// ...
```

Comment: Yes it works .. but I don't understand why !!! Can you please explain where was the problem and why you use this part (this.props.tracks &&)??? thank you very much :)

Comment: @AhmedEldawody `&&` checks if `props.tracks` isn't undefined or null, it's called short circuit evaluation

Comment: @AhmedEldawody I've updated my answer and explained  the reason `this.props.tracks` was undefined in your case.

Comment: You helped me a lot and thank you for your precious time and for your explanation
Really, you are a wonderful person <3 :)